# Setting up SSL on ubuntu 18.04.3 nginx

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, https

I'm trying to set up SSL on my Wordpress website. I'm hosting on Vultr but can't really finish SSL. I used Let's Encrypt Certbot in webroot. Now I have cert.pem chain.pem fullchain.pem privkey.pem files but I need to place server.crt server.key in my ssl directory. I'm guessing privkey.pem should be server.key but I have no idea how to generate server.crt.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I had to do was put cert.pem privkey.pem into nginx ssl dir and change their names to server.crt and server.key respectively.